# Roughly how long should I cook 3.5kg pork belly ribs in electric smoker?

Tags: barbecue, smoking, ribs, pork-belly

I know they are done when they are tender—not at a set number of hours. But we need to eat at about 6pm for logistical reasons.

Was thinking of putting them in at 4am so 13h total cook time + 1h rest.

Anyone done this before? Want to smoke at 225 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I don't see a question, you seem to have a plan already. Asking for opinions is off-topic, are you asking whether your cooking time is about right?

Comment: That sounds like a really long time. Spare rib, baby back, or country ribs? Just the ribs, or are they still attached to the belly?

Comment: @moscafj They are still attached to the belly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you are basically barbecuing pork belly with the ribs still attached.  [I like the approach these folks take](https://heygrillhey.com/bbq-smoked-pork-belly/).  You will want to maintain your smoker temperature at 225F (107C).  You will also want to use a probe thermometer.  They suggest treating the belly almost like one would treat brisket; that is, when the internal temperature reaches about 165F (74C), to wrap it in foil.  Then, continue until the internal temperature reaches 200F (93C).  Their belly took 8 hours using this method.  Given that yours still has the ribs attached it will likely take a bit longer.  It's hard to estimate time beyond this.  You will want to monitor temperature.  If it is done early, just keep it wrapped and place it in a cooler.